# how to check greater than and lower than condition and applying line feeds based on length

Tags: xml, xslt

hi can any one help out in this issue, how to check string length of a value based on that i need to prepare a conditions

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
   <Table>

<MSG_TYPE_CODE>O102N</MSG_TYPE_CODE>

<CTD_ORD_INS>//TAGBABNAGB2LXXX248</CTD_ORD_INS>

<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>477</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>

 </Table>

 </NewDataSet>
```

here is my xsl but it was not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="PackageId"  />
         <xsl:template match="/">           
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="SequenceB"  select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =477]"/>     
</xsl:template>



     <xsl:template mode ="SequenceB" match="NewDataSet/Table">

    <xsl:choose >

          <xsl:when  test ="substring(./MSG_TYPE_CODE,2,3)= '102'"  >

        <xsl:if test ="string-length(./CTD_ORD_INS)  >'35'" >
                <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':52D:',./CTD_ORD_INS)"/>,<xsl:text/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test ="string-length(./CTD_ORD_INS) <  '35'" >
                <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':52A:',./CTD_ORD_INS)"/>,<xsl:text/>
            </xsl:if>                
                        </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

i am checking the condition like if  the value is less than 35 char i m trying to concat the value with 52A is suppose the value is more than 35 i m trying to concat with 52D here one more condition i need to do if the length was more than 35 mns it should concat with 52D and it should parse as 1 to 35 in firstline and 36-70 in secondline line feed should to be happen can any suggest me some logic

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your template:

1. **When you wrap `35` in quotes, it is evaluated as a string, rather than a number.**
2. The `<` needs to be escaped (e.g. `&lt;`)
3. Your empty `<text/>` aren't doing anything. How you currently have them is the same as not having them there at all.

**Try this instead:**

```
<xsl:template mode ="SequenceB" match="NewDataSet/Table">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when  test ="substring(./MSG_TYPE_CODE,2,3)= '102'">
            <xsl:if test ="string-length(./CTD_ORD_INS)  > 35">
               <xsl:value-of select= "concat(':52D:',./CTD_ORD_INS)"/>
               <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test ="string-length(./CTD_ORD_INS) &lt;  35" >
                <xsl:value-of select= "concat(':52A:',./CTD_ORD_INS)"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>                
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**You could re-write it to be a little more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):**

```
<xsl:template mode ="SequenceB" match="NewDataSet/Table">

    <xsl:choose >

        <xsl:when  test ="substring(./MSG_TYPE_CODE,2,3)= '102'"  >
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test ="string-length(./CTD_ORD_INS)  > 35" >
                    <xsl:text>:52D:</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>:52A:</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:value-of select= "./CTD_ORD_INS"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>    

        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```